# Angularjs application: tip to send log message to server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, logging

we have an application client-server working with nodejs server side and angularjs client side.
We use requirejs to load resources.
We need to send log messages to server. Which is the best way to do this?

Server side we use log4js-node library to log our application (documentation: https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node)

Client side we already test multiple libraries to extend $log angular module, amoung with: Log4js, stacktrace, log4javascript

The last test we did it using log4javascript library (documentation: http://log4javascript.org/docs/index.html)

Below our code snippets:

## requirejs configuration

```
   require.config({
      baseUrl: 'app',
      paths: {
      //... 
      'log4javascript': '../vendor/log4javascript',   // tip to  log4javascript.js
      'logging': 'modules/logging'                  // our logging.js angular module 
      },
      shim: { 
      //...
      'logging': ['log4javascript']
      },
      deps: ['app']
      });
```

## logging.js module

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
var myApp = angular.module('logging', []);

myApp.factory('$log', function () {        
    var logger = log4javascript.getLogger('logging');
    var ajaxAppender = new log4javascript.AjaxAppender('http://myserver.com/api/log');
    logger.addAppender(ajaxAppender);
    return logger;
});

});
```

## app.js (our main)

```
require([...,"log4javascript"], function (...,log4javascript) {
   window.log4javascript = log4javascript;
   // ...
});
```

We use an AjaxAppender to an API that retrieve messages from client and format them          through log4js-node library.

What do you think about? Could you suggest us a better way to accomplish our purpose?